# How to convert debug.js to .js file after editing debug.js file

Tags: javascript, openlayers, library

How to convert a library file debug.js to .js file after editing the debug.js file. I edited opensource library file olgm.debug.js . Now i want to convert it into normal olgm.js file to use in application. Can any one help me to solve this problem. olgm is not supporting setStyle and setRotation etc.. For that i created new function edited in olgm.debug.js. Now how to convert to normal olgm.js.

Comment: Thank you chase choi, I got soultion, I edited in src folder and rebuild using GNU Make and node.js.

Comment: I moved my comment into the answer area.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't convert debug.js to build.js directly. If you want some changes, you have to modify the code which exists in src folder and re-build.